# MDT capture process injecting drivers, Why?

Tags: drivers, mdt

During the capture process from the MDT sequence, it will inject drivers into the sysprepped image, why would you need that?

I know you can prevent it from doing that simply by unchecking it, but why would you need to inject the drivers into the sysprepped image? I'm curious if I even need to do it or if I should do it. What scenario would you need an image with the injected drivers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Injecting drivers at deploy time allows you to keep drivers out of the image. it gives you exponentially more flexibility with your image.

So, lets say you have 12 different makes and models that you support. Instead of maintaining 12 different images that you have to update and/or rebuild every year, you build ONE image in a VM with no drivers.

Then, you can organize all your drivers in MDT by make and then model and inject drivers at deploy time.

It sounds like overkill, but once you have one image to rule them all, your life becomes much, much easier.

Comment: I understand this, this is why my question is opposite to that. When sysprepping an image, it injects the drivers into the image. Normally just storage or network drivers. I understand injecting them into the boot cd, but it would seem that the drivers should get injected when installing an OS, but sometimes this isn't always the case.

Comment: Gotcha, I understand now. Apologies. There is a step in the task sequence default to inject mass storage drivers for XP images, but it shouldn't do that for Vista and above. I use two different shares, one for building images and one for deploying images. This way you can keep drivers out of your images for sure and only inject at deploy time. I would avoid letting ANY drivers get in your image.

Comment: yea that's what I was kind of thinking. I do have to create XP images still, slowly getting away from that and moving on to Windows 7, which will be a lot easier.

Comment: @matt Is it possible that the drivers are being injected into the PE image that is used to boot for the capture process? This is where mass storage and network drivers would be needed, even for a capture.

Comment: @WinOutreach4 No, the PE image does have drivers injected, but they get injected when updating the deploy share. That's fine with me, but I would like to have a clean sysprep image.